# What is the best way to manage the switching of groups of variables?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, conditional-operator

### An example using the Conditional Operator.

```
void setSelected( bool selected )
{
    a = selected? SELECTED_VALUE_A: DEFAULT_VALUE_A;
    b = selected? SELECTED_VALUE_B: DEFAULT_VALUE_B;
    c = selected? SELECTED_VALUE_C: DEFAULT_VALUE_C;
}
```

### An example using an `if` and `temporaries`.

```
void setSelected( bool selected )
{
    a = DEFAULT_VALUE_A;
    b = DEFAULT_VALUE_B;
    c = DEFAULT_VALUE_C;
    if ( selected )
    {
        a = SELECTED_VALUE_A;
        b = SELECTED_VALUE_B;
        c = SELECTED_VALUE_C;
    }
}
```

### An example using functions

```
void setLook( int nA, float nB, std::string nC )
{
    a = nA;
    b = nB;
    c = nC;
}

void setSelected( bool selected )
{
    if ( selected )
        setLook( DEFAULT_VALUE_A, DEFAULT_VALUE_B, DEFAULT_VALUE_C );
    else
        setLook( SELECTED_VALUE_A, SELECTED_VALUE_B, SELECTED_VALUE_C );
}
```

### An alternate example using functions. Still uses `setLook`

```
void setLookSelected()
{
    setLook( SELECTED_VALUE_A, SELECTED_VALUE_B, SELECTED_VALUE_C );
}
void setLookNormal()
{
    setLook( DEFAULT_VALUE_A, DEFAULT_VALUE_B, DEFAULT_VALUE_C );
}
void setSelectedAF( bool selected )
{
    if ( selected )
        setLookSelected();
    else
        setLookNormal();
}
//Or just call
setLookSelected();
setLookNormal();
```

Comment: Your question should be much more condensed. Remove all the completely unnecessary context and boil it down to the conditional code alternatives in question. Even then it's maybe not a good question for Stack Overflow imho..

Comment: @gilligan What would be a good site to ask this question?

Comment: This site is fully devoted to asking and answering questions, but it's very hard to tell what you're asking. Can you state your question clearly in a few lines?

Comment: Maybe Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is best - but even there, a succinct presentation of the minimum necessary code would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the requirement:

> Set variable `a` to `c` if `b` is true or `d` otherwise

#### Using the conditional operator:

```
a = b ? c : d;
```

IMHO, as clear as it can get

#### Using temporaries and if:

```
a = c;
if (b)
   a = d;
```

Really ugly. You assign `c` to `a`, even if `!b`. Besides the awful readability, you encounter performance  drop, as you have a double assignment. The optimizer could take care of that, but don't count on it.

#### Using functions:

```
void setA(T x)
{
   a = x;
}

//....

if (b)
   setA(c);
else
   setA(d);
```

This could be useful if you have a lot of members that you want to set. Code maintenability will be improved. You'd only need to change in one place if you want different functionality. Not bad!

#### Alternate functions:

```
void setAC()
{
   a = c;
}
void setAD()
{
   a = d;
}

//...

if (b)
   setAC();
else
   setAD();
```

Another option I'd advise against. What if you don't want to check only for `b` in the future? What if the two variants aren't exclusive, i.e. you want to combine `ID_NODE_GLOW_SELECT` with `ID_NODE_COLOR_NORMAL` for some other condition?

**Conclusion:** I'd use the first variant for simple, small cases, and the functions with parameters for large classes, where you set a lot of members. I'd definetely stay away from options 2 & 4.

Comment: Your if version seems strange. Why not if-else? I guess you're just copying what he did....

Comment: @Hurkyl I am. Using an if in a normal way is pretty much identical to the ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer isn't clean and obvious, sometimes it means you're asking the wrong question.

Scanning your code, I suspect there are two design changes that would be a good idea:

- Collect all of the style data into a single `sprite_style` class. This way, you can make some named constants for each of the various styles, and then you can change the style with one simple `set_style` function call.
- Move the selection code out of the `sprite` class -- let the `sprite` class be just the basic stuff you need for a sprite. Move this style switching stuff into a subclass, or even better, into an event handler that's triggered upon state change.